# page reloading on client click in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExpand" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Expand" ToolTip="Expand text area to view all text"
            Enabled="true" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnShrink" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Shrink" ToolTip="Shrink text area to original size"
            Enabled="false" />
<script type="text/javascript">                     
    document.getElementById('<%= this.btnExpand.ClientID %>').addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= this.txtTextArea.ClientID %>').clientHeight < document.getElementById('<%= this.txtTextArea.ClientID %>').scrollHeight) {
            document.getElementById('<%= this.txtTextArea.ClientID %>').style.height = document.getElementById('<%= this.txtTextArea.ClientID %>').scrollHeight+ "px";
            document.getElementById('<%= this.btnShrink.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('<%= this.btnExpand.ClientID %>').disabled = true; 
        }
        return false;
    });
    document.getElementById('<%= this.btnShrink.ClientID %>').addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById('<%= this.txtTextArea.ClientID %>').style.height = '80px';
        document.getElementById('<%= this.btnShrink.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('<%= this.btnExpand.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        return false;
    });
```

page is reloading on shrink button click in IE, but working fine in Chrome

Comment: can you add your html markup for shrink btn?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnExpand" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Expand" ToolTip="Expand text area to view all text"
                Enabled="true" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
             <asp:Button ID="btnShrink" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Shrink" ToolTip="Shrink text area to original size"
                Enabled="false" />

Comment: you have OnClientClick="return false;" for btnExpand but not "btnShrink"

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess you need to change:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShrink" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Shrink" 
 ToolTip="Shrink text area to original size" Enabled="false" />
```

To:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShrink" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Shrink" 
ToolTip="Shrink text area to original size" Enabled="false" 
OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

EDIT:

Try changing your markup to this:

```
<input type="button" runat="server" class="btn" title="Shrink text area to original size" onclick="return false;"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried this for "btnShrink" but the page is still reloading..

Comment: If you don't need your button to post back then there is no need to make it a server control (asp:button) - use input control instead